# pass value from python to javascript using jinja

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I am passing a list of json from my python code as

```
  return render_template("audio.html", data = play_list)
```

each json is of type `{"title":"title","link":"link"}`

```
[json1,json2.. ]
```

My javascript has a hardcoded list which works like following

```
var data = [ {title: "title", link: "link"} ....]
```

Note that title key doesnt have any quotes..
But now instead of using this hardcoded list in javascript, I want to use the data sent by python..
How do I get this data from python to jinja to this javascript object.
Thakns

Comment: `var data = {{ play_list }};`?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi For some reason.. the double quotes are being translated  to weird characters... {&#39;url&#39;: &#39;foo.com&#39;, &#39;title&#39;: u&#39;no more sorrow  live at milton keynes &#39;}

Comment: `var data = {{ play_list|safe }};`, then?

Comment: Ok.. Now it prints the list.. but I see this error on console Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string on same line

Comment: @IsmailBadawi: Also, how do i remove quotes around url and title in javascript?

Comment: You don't need to remove the quotes. It's valid either way.

Comment: I don't think we can really diagnose the SyntaxError without taking a look at the contents of `play_list`...

Comment: @IsmailBadawi: Here is the error string on console

var playlist = [{'url': 'foo.com', 'title': u'no more sorrow  live at milton keynes '}, {'url': 'foo.com', 'title': u'leave out all the rest  single version '}, {'url': 'foo.com', 'title': u'one step closer  live at milton keynes '}, {'url': 'foo.com', 'title': u'valentine s day  live from frankfurt germany_ jan 20  08 '}, {'url': 'foo.com', 'title': u'runaway  album version '}];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55232/discussion-between-fraz-and-ismail-badawi).

Comment: Aah. `var data = {{ play_list|tojson|safe }}`?